# window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit; not working on android chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following piece of code which works fine on PC and laptop safari , mozilla and chrome browsers but not on mobile
why and how to replace the code with other working code so that it works in the same way

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" async>
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
document.getElementById('ControlCode').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('ControlCode').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is it getting into the confirmExit() function?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? By the time the `beforeunload` handler is called, the browser is already about to leave your page, so changes to the DOM won't be visible.

Comment: when i come back to the page , they will be visible

Comment: i am trying to hide a div on page 1 if i open a link and it takes me to a new tab or page 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on it.
I can confirm to you that to obtain equal behavior you have to bind the callback like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = window.onunload = function(){
       /** YOUR CODE HERE **/
};
```

Best if placed in top of the page, to get it executed also on page load not completed.

Comment: I use it everyday without problems. Can you paste your code inside the callback here?

Comment: thank you for the response .
this code is working fine.
there was an error in my implementation.
figured it out.
Thanks again